# Logstash filter doesn't work in Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm trying to apply a filter in logstash for the logs that arrive to me, these logs arrive in json from a busybox pod where there is also filebeat, this is the script inside the busybox pod that generates the logs:

```bash
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "while true; do echo '{\"time\": \"'$(date -u)'\", \"message\": \"Hello,World!\"}' >> /var/log/busybox.log; echo '{\"time\": \"'$(date -u)'\", \"message\": \"Ciao,Mondo!\"}' >> /var/log/busybox.log; sleep 1; done"]
```

This is the logstash configmap:

```bash
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: logging
data:
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    filter {
      json {
        source => "message"
      }
      if "Hello" in [message] {
        mutate { add_field => { "language" => "EN" } }
      } else if "Ciao" in [message] {
        mutate { add_field => { "language" => "IT" } }
      }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "https://elasticsearch:9200" ]
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
        user => "elastic"
        password => "mypass"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I would like the kibana discovery dashboard to show that if it's English or Italian, tell me, but it doesn't work, that is, I can see the logs on kibana but without the filter